# Django: many to many reverse of its own type

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, mezzanine

I have a model called "Service", which subclasses a "Page" model. This is defined as follows:

```
class Service(Page):
    content = RichTextField(null="True", blank="True")
    links = models.ManyToManyField("pages.Page", blank=True, related_name="service_links")
```

The "links" many-to-many relationship should allow every service to link to multiple pages (regardless of if they are a service)

I want to be able to pull these results into its own service page (which I'll call Page A in this example) so that it can show these links to the end user.

I am currently using:
`related_links = Service.objects.filter(links=request.page.id)` but this only works for Pages that are pointing to Page A, not Page A's links.

How can I reverse this filter to get the links on Page A?

Answer (score 0):

For a page with id `N`:

```
Page.objects.get(id=N).service_set.all()
```

Comment: Thanks, but that just returns me an AttributeError: 'Page' object has no attribute 'service_set'

Comment: What version of Django are you using? Also, does Page inherit from `models.Model`?

Comment: Django 1.10.5, the page model is based on that from Mezzanine, see https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/blob/master/mezzanine/pages/models.py#37

Answer (score 0):

You need '[in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in)' Django lookup

```
related_links = Service.objects.filter(links_in=request.page.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the solution was much simpler than expected.

```
related_links = list()
for link in request.page.service.links.all():
    related_links.append(link)
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is a mezzanine specific thing or a generic django thing but this seems to work.